# Keepass 2.32 on Windows 10, keyboard inputs gibberish after restart

Tags: keepass

i have installed keepass a few days ago and have been using the autotype obfuscation feature successfully. However, I've been having issues with the keyboard entering garbled text when I restart the machine after having used keepass: the keys I strike do not correspond to what appears on the screen. The issue goes away after **two** restarts weirdly. I was wondering of anybody else has been having the same issue ?

Comment: Also: [please capitalize the 1. person sg pronoun](//english.stackexchange.com/q/172).

Comment: @SmokeDispenser There only seems to be one lowercase i in there. Faster to simply correct that one mistake (my edits still need peer review...)